# Copy image from one Word document to another using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, copy-paste

I have a word document with one picture in it, nothing else. I would like to copy this picture to another Word document using vb.net.
Any ideas on how this could be done?

What i have so far is this:

```
Dim vk_word_app As Word.Application = New Word.Application
Dim vk_new_doc As Word.Document = vk_word_app.Documents.Open("final.docx")

vk_word_app.Activate()
vk_word_app.Visible = False

For i as integer = 0 To 9 Step 1   
    Dim vk_my_doc As Word.Document = vk_word_app.Documents.Open("test.docx")
    vk_my_doc.Select()
    vk_word_app.Selection.Copy()
    vk_new_doc.Select()
    vk_word_app.Selection.PasteSpecial()
    vk_my_doc.Close()
Next

    vk_new_doc.Save()
    vk_word_app.Quit()
```

The image gets copied to the new file but every new one that is copied overwrite the previous one so in the reulst final.docx there is only one image instead of 10. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try a For Each statement instead of a For statement. A For...Next structure is used when you want to repeat a set of statements a set number of times. A For Each...Next loop is used when you want to do a set of statements for each element of a collection or array.

```
For Each i as integer = 0 To 9 Step 1 
*your code*
Next
```

Comment: This is not true. The step 1 (redundantly) states the loop to increase i by 1.

Comment: a For Each statement as you wrote it gives a syntax error. I am quick certain that there is nothing wrong with the way the loop is build. I think the issue lies with the WORD api overwriting the previous picture when the newest one is pasted.